# can we say the relation between two countries is sour

Tags: word-usage

I've wrote:

> The relation between Iran and Emirate is sour

to mean the relation isn't good, or is negative. It's not hostile but yet not well.
Did I use the right word?
Could you explain more about this phrase?

Answer (score 3):

You could say the *relationship* is sour, or has turned sour.

You could also say the same about *relations* (plural) between them.

"Relation" in the singular form isn't correct in this context.

Comment: Thanks, I may still have problem between "relation" and "relationship". You mean "relations" could substitute "relationship? because I think I've read much like "the relation between the US and Canada, the relation between X and Y.... Maybe I could ask it as another question.

Comment: @Ahmad It’s either “the relationship” or (no article) “relations”. “The relation(s)” (with article) is not used in this context.

Comment: I think "has soured", indicating a change for the worse, is more idiomatic than "is sour".

Comment: I agree with @Jack O'Flaherty – when "sour" is used in this way, either as a verb or an adjective, it just about always describes a **change for the worse**. If a relationship has gone from good (or even just OK) to bad, we can say it "has soured," "has turned sour," or "has gone sour." But if it has **always** been bad, we aren't likely to say it "is sour." (Instead might say it is "bad," "difficult," "tense," "acrimonious," or any number of other things.)